# require 'package vs with-eval-after-load 'package

Tags: require, load, conditionals, eval-after-load

```
(require 'eglot)
(do-something)
```

There's another..

```
(with-eval-after-load 'eglot
  (do-something)
)
```

They seem to do the same, are there any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read their descriptions. Not at all the same.

`with-eval-after-load` doesn't load its first argument; `require` does.

Even if the `require` fails in your scenario, `(do-something)` is invoked. In the other case it's not invoked unless `eglot` has been successfully loaded.